# Netcat not Working

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, pipe, netcat

I'm just beginning to work with bash scripts and I've tried to get a simple pipe to work:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                   

mkfifo apipe
cat apipe | nc -l $1 | /home/matt/testprogram > apipe
```

Given that the port number works and the program works as I want it to, what could be making this script mess up?

My program is supposed to print some text as well as take in some user input using fgets. When I run my shell script, I want it to act like as if I was just running the program normally. When I run it I just get it blanking out and not doing anything, and I have to break it with ctrl+C.

I type into the terminal something like:

```
sh testnc.sh 2342
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you explained what you want to achieve and which errors you get.

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried to make it a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using NC wrong.  `nc -l $1` is listening for an external connection on that port.  So you could run something like this:

host 1:

```
nc -l <port> | /home/matt/testprogram
```

host 2:

```
cat files | nc <host1> <port>
```

But the usage that you are doing makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to get network server like behavior. Do you know how I should edit my code to do that (because I assumed that was what my code did)?

Comment: Have a look at `ncat` it's like nc version 2 (: the syntax is easier and more consistent.